# Reusing useEffect code in every component in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, dry, wow.js

I have a `useEffect` which initializes `wowjs` in a component like so:

```
import WOW from "wowjs";

const HomePage = () => {

useEffect(() => {
        const wow = new WOW.WOW({
        boxClass: "wow",
        animateClass: "animated",
        offset: 0,
        mobile: false,
        live: true,
        scrollContainer: null
      });
      wow.init();
    }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      ....
    </div>
  )
}
```

I want this `useEffect` in many components so that the `wowjs` animations can run on every route change. How do i avoid repeating this code in my reactjs project?

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As RTW mentionned in his comment, you could use a HOC to centralize this code.

But as it seems you have been already hooked by hooks, I would suggest to put this code in a custom `useWow` hook and just call this hook in every component where you may need it.

```
const useWow = () => {

  const initWow = () => {
    const wow = new WOW.WOW({
        boxClass: "wow",
        animateClass: "animated",
        offset: 0,
        mobile: false,
        live: true,
        scrollContainer: null
      });
    wow.init();
  }

  return { initWow }
}
```

And then in your component

```
const { initWow } = useWow()

useEffect(() => {
 initWow();
}, [])
```